# How do I add factors to a new variable in a small dataframe in R?

Tags: r

Quick question: I have a small dataset that I melted and now would like to add a column variable:

```
> df
          taxa  spring summer     fall LocationA LocationB
1 Chironominae 1957.50 537.54 3396.765  1712.196   2958.642
2   Culicoides  863.53 343.08 2796.647  1907.804   1384.642
3     Naididae  949.88  40.75  147.569   641.911     91.566
4     Asioplax 1799.41 163.04  119.882     0.000   1343.528
5     Nematoda    0.00 166.00   27.647    53.679     45.057
6  Stilobezzia    0.00  20.38  885.961   605.179    222.321

taxa <- melt(df)

> taxa
           taxa   variable    value
1  Chironominae     spring 1957.500
2    Culicoides     spring  863.530
3      Naididae     spring  949.880 .....
```

How do I add a column for "variable.type" that defines whether the "variable" is a *season* (rows 1:18) or a *location* (rows 19:30)? I tried:

```
taxa$variable.type <- c("Season"[1:18], "Location"[19:30])
```

but just ended up with a column with lots of NAs.

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is the way you want to reflow your data? Season and location are two different concepts of data for taxa and you might be better of by not varying location in your melting.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've been mulling that over too... I'm trying to find a useful way to summarise the data to non-scientists and this was getting me one step closer to a plot I am playing with. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df$variable.type <- ifelse(df$variable %in% c("spring","summer","fall"),"season","location")
```

Comment: You're awesome! Worked a charm. Good to know I can use ifelse with a factor. :)